# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'segmentObject' does not exist in type 'ViddlSegment'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

This is my interface

```
export interface ViddlSegment {
  id: number
  viddlId: number
  from: number
  to: number
  include: boolean
}
```

I am trying to declare an empty object of type `ViddlSegment`.

```
const segment:ViddlSegment = {
  id: 0,
  viddlId: 0,
  from: 0,
  to: 0,
  include: true
}; 
  const [segmentList, setSegmentList] = useState<ViddlSegment[]>([segment]);
  const handleRowAdd = () => {
  setSegmentList([...segmentList, {segment}]);
};
```

Function call `onClick()`. I am getting error on this line when i try to add empty object to my list

Comment: I am a beginner in react. I am trying to add rows dynamically in react based on length on segmentList.

Comment: what is [segment] in useState?

Comment: segment is an intentional empty object of type ViddlSegment. Initially my segmentList will have this state i.e. will contain one empty object.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add an object to your list, but you are passing an object with a key of "segment" and a value of the object you want to add.

You should be passing an empty object:

```
const handleRowAdd = () => {
  setSegmentList([...segmentList, {}]);
};
```